# Django and thread?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

when I set my command runserver whatever the url that I am running a test is executing if temperature is more than 30 a mail is sent . this is my mail application . I have to this with thread I haven't found how to do it . Please help me I am a beginner in Django 
mail/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


def index(request,self):

    subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message', 'attention ! la temperature a depasse le maximum ')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', 'djdsidjff@gmail.com')

    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [ 'ajshjdhuie@gmail.com' ])
            return HttpResponse('templates/mail.html')
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('mail')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

Comment: Try this tutorial on threaded programming [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: If you are trying to send email asynchronously, use celery along with django